# Do BitBucket hooks fire on branch commits?

Tags: bitbucket, appharbor

If I have multiple branches in my BitBucket repository, and push changes to one of the branches, do the hooks fire?

I want to ensure that my hook to AppHarbor only fires on pushes to the master, but I can't find any configuration on whether that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, they do.

However, with AppHabor, I can now attach to a specific branch in the repository. When done this way, only changes to that branch cause AppHarbor to get the updates and republish my website.

So I now have 3 "permanent" branches...

1. "dev" that I can push to any time and is not monitored by AppHarbor
2. "uat" that I pull from "dev" when desired, and this updates my UAT web site
3. "live" that I pull from "uat" when desired, and this updates my Live web site